# Observable.merge behaves differently in an epic

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

In a React/Redux application, I use Redux Observable and I want an epic to output two distinct actions.

First, I tried this:

```
const epic1 = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType("A")
    .mapTo({ type: "B" })
    .merge(Observable.of({ type: "C" }));
```

As it didn't work, I had to switch to:

```
const epic2 = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType("D")
    .mergeMap(value =>
      Observable.merge(
        Observable.of({ type: "E" }),
        Observable.of({ type: "F" })
      )
    );
```

See this CodeSandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/l52ym6n8vz).

The thing is, I'm not sure to understand why the first try didn't work because in the example below, it works well outside an epic:

```
var observable = Observable.of({type: "A"})
  .mapTo({type: "B"})
  .merge(Observable.of({ type: "C" }));

observable.subscribe(value => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    values: [...prevState.values, value]
  }));
});
```

Any idea why it behaves differently in the epic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't because you're using epics. The first example uses `.merge(Observable.of({ type: "C" }))` so it subscribes to `Observable.of({ type: "C" })` immediately what you subscribe to `epic1`. However, you're using redux so the subscription happens somewhere inside redux and `Observable.of({ type: "C" })` emits immediately without you even knowing when it happened. Then any other action `.ofType("A")` makes no change because `.merge(Observable.of({ type: "C" }))` has already emitted its only value.

This also explain why the example you're mention at the end of your question works as expected.

On the other hand when you use `mergeMap` the callback is invoked on each emission from the source observable (on every `action$.ofType("D")` action). It creates new `E` and `F` actions that are merged immediately to the chain.